# Is "Within" a Substitute for "in the"?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know the correct usage of this preposition:

Is it correct to say:

"Position within the Organization"

or

"Position in the Organization"?

In which context is it correct to use one over the other or are they exactly equivalent?

Comment: Within the event of an emergency, no.

Comment: Obviously, the answer is _no_, since you yourself substituted _within_ for _in_, not for _in the_.

Comment: @oerkelens substitution does not imply a difference in all cases.

Comment: What I meant is that your question is about substituting _within_ for _in the_, but your examples substitutes _withing the_ for _in the_, or _within_ for _in_. The article  is there in both cases, though your question implies it can be elided, which, obviously, it can't.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Mika'il If **in the** were to become **within**, then *position **in the** organization* would become *position **within** organization*. But it doesn't. Instead, it's *position **in** [the] organization* that becomes *position **within** [the] organization*. The word **the** is left alone—only **in** is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes their usage depends on the context.
'In' is a more firm preposition. 
If the organisation is very big and the position-holder in question is not very prominent inside the organisation, then use "within".
Otherwise, use "in".
For eg. consider the Company 'Apple' :
Mr ABC holds a position *within* this organisation.
Tim Cook holds the top position *in* the organisation.